# Scale / Resize StdPicture in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have looked far and wide and reached the end of my wits trying to figure out how to do this. I have looked on [XtremeVBTalk.com](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/) and the rest of the internet on how to resize a damn StdPicture!

Does anyone know how to do this? Is this even possible?

Thank you so much in advance. I desire not to use any type libraries etc. so if that is offered in a solution I don't think I will be able to use it.

I'm not using A picturebox control at all.

Say I have the following function header, and an StdPicture is passed in:

```
Private Function EncodeImageToBase64(ByRef Image As StdPicture) As String
```

I then have the following declarations where I intend on encoding the StdPicture to base64:

```
  Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
  Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
  Dim bColor() As Byte
  Dim bMask() As Byte
  Dim bImage() As Byte
  Dim lCrcTable() As Long
  Dim lWidth As Long
  Dim lHeight As Long
  EncodeImageToBase64 = vbNullString

  If Image Is Nothing Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  Call CRCTable(lCrcTable)
  Call Icon2Arrays(Image, bColor, bMask, lWidth, lHeight)
  If Not CreatePngByteArray(bImage, lWidth, lHeight, bColor, bMask, lCrcTable) Then
    Debug.Assert False
    Exit Function
  End If
```

However, before calling that, I want to cut the image's width and height in half. *How can I do so?* CreatePngByteArray only supports 16x16 PNGs and I am using 32x32, so I'd like to cut them down in order to pass the asserts they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I spent quite some time that I didn't really have on this one, because I didn't know the answer to begin with, but I was still interested in finding out what the potential solution was.

The following answer is my understanding of what you are trying to do, but may not be the answer to the question itself, so it could very well be considered wrong.

So, here's what I came up with. You will need to use an IPictureDisp object *instead of* an StdPicture object. You will also need to use a PictureBox control, even if you don't really want to.

Create a new project. Add a form, or open an existing one if one is provided. Set the ScaleMode of the form to pixels. Add a PictureBox control on the form. Set the AutoRedraw property of the PictureBox control to 'True', the BorderStyle property of the control to 'None', and the Height and Width properties of the control to 16 pixels each. Add the following code to the form, and modify the location and type of the image that you want to resize, and then the location to save it to:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim TestPic As IPictureDisp
    Set TestPic = LoadPicture("C:\Users\Your Name\Desktop\image.gif")
    With TestPic
        .Render Picture1.hDC, 0, 16, 16, -17, 0, 0, .width, .height, 0
    End With
    SavePicture Picture1.Image, "C:\Users\Your Name\Desktop\image2.bmp"

End Sub
```

The image can start with any of the types that Visual Basic 6 supports (.bmp, .cur, .gif, .ico, .jpeg or .jpg, and .wmf), but must always be saved in bitmap format. Please note that Visual Basic 6 does not support PNG file formats at all, so you will not be able to use any VB6 functions to open PNG files or create them.

I would be interested in other solutions that other people come up with.

**Edit:** Fixed dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to save the image, so I won't be doing that part. This seems like major overkill since I don't want the form or anything, I just want that image that I already have, to be smaller. better than nothing though! I'll wait it out a bit more and then accept this if nothing else comes along.

Comment: @Taylor Your welcome. I have revised the answer, as it turns out I didn't use the right dimensions for the image, thus causing the image to be slightly smaller than what it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean inside the PICTUREBOX control or inside an IMAGE CONTROL? Because If I remember correctly it has a STRETCH property which autofits the image to the container

Comment: I updated the question for more specificity (same comment as to Dan). I'm not using a PictureBox. The image was originally displayed in an MSFlexGrid cell.

Comment: Please DO NOT change the question, If you wish to ask another question, post another thread please. This is so that anyone who is trying to help you does not get marked down by future readers who may not follow your original question. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't change it! I just added more information to help those who are generously trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

@Zaf Khan beat me to it. I have something similar where I have a PictureBox. Under behaviour I have SizeMode set to StretchImage then when I load an image like so

```
LoadWebImageToPictureBox(ImagePreview, SelectedFile)
```

it auto fits.

Comment: I updated the question for more specificity. I'm not using a PictureBox. The image was originally displayed in an MSFlexGrid.